# Change Text Box Value Based on Select Input with Selected Attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am attempting to change the value of a text input based on the user selecting a value from a pulldown. I have got it working using the following,

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function() {                                       
        $("#name").live("change", function() {
          $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        })
     });                                     
</script>

<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="Elvis">Elvis</option> 
<option value="Frank">Frank</option> 
<option value="Jim">Jim</option> 
</select>

<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

This all work fine.  What I am trying to achieve now is for the pre-selected item to show by default when the user re-visits the form if they wish to edit their choice. At the moment the select just defaults to 'Please Select...'. Is their anyway to force the select to show the value from the text input when the page loads?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#name option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $("#firstname").val();
    }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#name").live("change", function() {

        $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="Elvis">Elvis</option> 
<option value="Frank">Frank</option> 
<option value="Jim">Jim</option> 
</select>

<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="Elvis" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Check it now is this what you want

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt seem to work at all now either for default values or live change

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

  $(document).on("change", "#name", function() {

     $("#firstname").val( this.value ); // this.value is enough for you

  }).val( $('#firstname').val() ).change(); // for pre-selection trigger

});
```

#### Note

Instead of `.live()` use `.on()` with jQuery 1.7+, because `live()` is deprecated.

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event handling is:

```
$(StaticParent).on( eventName, target, handlerFunction );
```

Where, `StaticParent` means the non-dynamic parent container of `target` element on which you want to bind event.

So, for above case it would be better to use any static parent of `#name` instead of `document`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                       
    $("#name").live("change", function() {
      $("#firstname").val($(this).val());
    })
 }); ​
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a try: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/mw4dY/

Basically onload I'm just selecting an option by the value, setting it to selected and then calling the change event. Your change event takes care of the rest.

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                       
  $("#name").live("change", function() {
    $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
  });
  $('#name option[value=Frank]').attr('selected','selected').change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code on `$(document).ready`

```
$("#name").val($("#firstname").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#name').val($('#firstname').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

To remember the form values you can use [cookie functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value = readCookie('fname');
    if (value) {
        $("#firstname").val(value);
        $('#name option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
    $("#name").on("change", function() {
        var value = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
        $("#firstname").val(value);
        createCookie('fname',value,31);
    });
});

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/JgSzx/) - if you revisit this page, the name will be set back as on the page leave.