# select value in dropdown dynamically change value in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on this form where it has  drop down and text box.
When value selected in one drop-down should  change value in text-box dynamically.

for eg if I select a value "3" in select box then

```
select ename from emp where eid ='3';
```

and result should be in text box

Similarly form has multiple drop-down list with respective text-box.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly have a [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to SO & come back again with your efforts & specific problem you face.

Comment: Please show your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#empID').change(function(){
    $.get('getEmpInfo.php',{empId:$(this).val()},function(data){
    $('#emp_id').val(data);
 });
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select name="empID" id="empID">
    <option value="">Select Emp</option>
    <option value='1'>Emp1</option>
    <option value='2'>Emp2</option>
    <option value='3'>Emp3</option>
    <option value='4'>Emp4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" />
</body>
</html>
```

**AT getEmpInfo.php PAge**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['empId'])){
  // connection should be on this page  
    $sql = mysql_query("select ename from emp where eid =".$_REQUEST['empId']);
    $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    echo $res['ename'];die;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but dont want copy the list value to textbox i want take that value & call a function  where i will get result  "select ename from emp where eid ='{ empID select value }'" and return that value to textbox emp_id

Comment: Thanx what if i have multiple select box and respective textbox then i have create php page like  getEmpInfo.php for each select box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nafnR/2/)**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#name option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#firstname").val();
}).attr('selected', true);

$("#name").live("change", function() {

    $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
});
```

});​

My Be Duplicate : **[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847643/change-text-box-value-based-on-select-input-with-selected-attribute/11847676#11847676)**

Answer (score 0):

For this solutions you can try:

//set textbox value change dynamic after dropbox had changed.

```
$('#' + yourDropBoxId).change(function ()
{
var dropDownValue = $('#'+ yourId).val();
// set new value for textbox
$('#' + yourTextBoxId).val(dropDownValue); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code which contains two textboxes :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  $(document).ready(function(){  $('#empID').change(function(){   $.get('1.php',{empId:$(this).val()},function(data){   $('#emp_id').val(data);});});});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">  $(document).ready(function(){  $('#d1').change(function(){   $.get('1.php',{d1:$(this).val()},function(data){   $('#t1').val(data);});});});</script>


</head>

<body>
<?php

$bdd = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'member');

$r= mysqli_query($bdd, "select * from info");
?>

<br>تشكيلة مباراة :<select name="empID" id="empID">
                   <option value="">Select name from List...</option>
<?php 
while ($d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))

    {
        ?>

        <option value="<?=$d["prenom"];?>  <?=$d["nom"];?>"><?=$d["prenom"];?>  <?=$d["nom"];?></option>
        <?php 
    }
    ?>

</select>
<input type="text" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" /><br><hr>

<br>تشكيلة مباراة :<select name="d1" id="d1">
                   <option value="">Select name from List...</option>
<?php 
$r1= mysqli_query($bdd, "select * from info");
while ($d1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1))

    {
        ?>

        <option value="<?=$d1["prenom"];?>  <?=$d1["nom"];?>"><?=$d1["prenom"];?>  <?=$d1["nom"];?></option>
        <?php 
    }
    ?>

</select>
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" />


</body>
</html>
```

PHP page :"1.php"

```
    <?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['empId'])){    echo $_REQUEST['empId']; }
if(isset($_REQUEST['d1'])){    echo $_REQUEST['d1']; }
?>
```